# Python IndexError: no such group

Tags: python, html, regex

I started learning Python earlier today and as my first project I wanted to make a script that shows me today's weather forecast.

My script:

```
import urllib2, re

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.wetter.com/wetter_aktuell/wettervorhersage/heute     /deutschland/oberhausen/DE0007740.html')
html = url.read()
url.close()

x = re.search("""<dl><dd><strong>(?P<uhrzeit>.*)""", html, re.S)
x = re.search("""<dd><span class="degreespan" style="font-weight:normal;">(?P<temp>.*)""",  html, re.S)
print x.group('uhrzeit'), x.group('temp')
```

I used [this](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_unter_Linux%3a_Netzwerk) as template. When I run this script I get an Index Error *no such groups*

Comment: You should really use an HTML parser for parsing HTML not regex. Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/763505 .

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `x`.

Maybe you want:

```
x = re.search("""<dl><dd><strong>(?P<uhrzeit>.*)""", html, re.S)
y = re.search("""<dd><span class="degreespan" style="font-weight:normal;">(?P<temp>.*)""",  html, re.S)
print x.group('uhrzeit'), y.group('temp')
```

And I can't belive that the site you linked advocates using regular expressions for extracting information from HTML.

Comment: Using this I get "AttributeError: "'noneType' Object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Then your expression was not found (matched).

Comment: Really, don't use regex to parse HTML. Use some parser like beautifulsoup or something.